# how to enable Samsung Pass support on login screen

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-knox

I have a login screen (with username and password) in my app. I want that after logging in, Samsung Pass asks to store the credentials and fills the login credentials in the future.

It works on the twitter app, but not in my app? My current login input fields look like this:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:autofillHints="username"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:autofillHints="password"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When I login, there is no prompt from Samsung Pass asking to store the credentials like it is in the twitter app. Anyone got an idea what I have to do or change to get the Samsung Pass support to work?

Comment: The "pass programming guide" from Samsung might help you: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass/guide